# How do I implement IHttpActionResult so that it respects the Accept header?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I want over override BadRequest() in my ApiController so that it returns an object with validation errors. Here's my first crack at implementing a "RichBadRequest" result:

```
public class RichBadRequestResponse : BadRequestResult
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Errors { get; set; } = new string[0];
    public string Message { get; set; }

    private HttpRequestMessage _request;
    public RichBadRequestResponse(HttpRequestMessage request) : base(request)
    {
        _request = request;
    }

    public override Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var dataObj = new
        {
            errors = Errors.ToArray(),
            message = Message ?? string.Join(", ", Errors)
        };
        if (_request.Headers.Accept.Contains(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("applicaiton/xml")))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Foo");
        }
        var resp = _request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, dataObj);
        return Task.FromResult(resp);
    }
}
```

Then in my controller I just have:

```
public class MyApiController : ApiController
{
    protected override BadRequestResult BadRequest()
    {
        return BadRequest("There was an error with your request", null);
    }

    protected RichBadRequestResponse BadRequest(string message, IEnumerable<string> validationErrors)
    {
        validationErrors = validationErrors ?? new string[0];
        var result = new RichBadRequestResponse(Request)
        {
            Message = "There was an error with your request",
            Errors = validationErrors.ToArray()
        };
        return result;
    }
}
```

This works just fine... *however* it doesn't respect the Accept header. For whatever reason, this always seems to get returned as a JSON object. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you have a typo "applicaiton/xml"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going through your i found that CreateResponse was not returning XML while CreateErrorResponse is returning JSON/XML or according to Accept header.

Here, in CreateErrorResponse, you can add your dictionary collection as you require.

```
    public override Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var dataObj = new
        {
            errors = errors.ToArray(),
            message = Message ?? string.Join(", ", errors)
        };

        if (_request.Headers.Accept.Contains(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("applicaiton/xml")))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Foo");
        }
        ///// Changed Line
        var resp = _request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, yourDictionaryCollection);
        return Task.FromResult(resp);
    }
```